# Docker default-ulimit nofile setting

Tags: linux, docker

/etc/docker/daemon.json has the following contents

```
{ 
 "live-restore": true,
  "default-ulimits": {
    "memlock": {
      "Hard": -1,
      "Name": "memlock",
      "Soft": -1
    }
  }
}
```

We want to set nofile limit in /etc/sysconfig/docker ex `OPTIONS="--default-ulimit nofile=1024000:1024000"` this should be in sysconfig/docker and not in daemon.json.

After setting it up docker was not coming up due to default-ulimit flag exist in daemon.json file as well. so how to override this setting? Please advise

Comment: Why not put all settings in one file? Splitting them across the two doesn't appear to be supported. And the `/etc/sysconfig/docker` is a RedHat specific file that is not supported by docker.

Comment: Thanks. we are enabling this flag nofile=xxx at runtime, in the sense at the time of node creation. how do pass this flag using linux command to that file? earlier I was using this cmd ===="echo -e '#By default we limit the number of open files per container\\nOPTIONS=\"--default-ulimit nofile=100000:100000\"' >> /etc/sysconfig/docker && service docker restart"====

Comment: By default, the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file doesn't exist. So I recommend updating how you create this file to include the content you need. `jq` may be a good way to edit the file if you need to create it uniquely per node.